# I would like to get a Facebook pixel ID for testing purposes that is not linked to an actual ad account

Tags: facebook, testing, ads

I am trying to set a testing environment for our marketing data. My goal is to test the segment.com analytics.js implementation on our website and the integration to google analytics (test set-up is done) & Facebook ads (not done).

For the latter I have linked a Facebook integration to a test source within segment and created a simple website to run identify and track calls through the console. Now I would love to see if segment.com sends and facebook receives the correct data when sending these events. For this I need a pixel ID to add to the segment.com integration.

Would anyone know how to get a testing ad account, with working pixel tracking? 
I have tried the Whitehat account, but that one would get stuck at 98% when loading the admin panel.